# Cannot install Windows Installer package on Windows XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, windows-xp-mode

Whenever I try to install a particular MSI from Windows XP Mode located on my local hard drive, it fails with the following error:

[image: The Windows Installer does not permit installation from a Remote Desktop Connection.]

Why is this error occurring and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Copy the file to the drive of the virtual machine and install it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows XP Mode is secretly a [headless Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_computer) that Windows launches a Remote Desktop connection to. Because it's headless, it can do a lot of stuff in the background (i.e. logging in with the 'Secure' Windows 7-style login dialog before Windows XP even loads), so that when it's booted, you're ready to work. You will need to connect to it as a machine, not as a Windows instance.

[This site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/06/19/disabling-integrated-mode-in-windows-virtual-pc.aspx) describes the Integrated VM Features, and how to disable them. To summarize:

> Start the VM
>   Select Tools->Disable Integrated Mode
>   When you see the loading dialog
>   [image]
>   Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>

This disables the integration features, and makes it act more like a virtual machine; for example, you can start the system in Safe Mode from that point. Another big difference is that XP Mode won't be running as a Remote Desktop Session then, and you should be able to install the MSI package then.

Comment: So, is there a Group Policy setting that disables the "Disconnect" button in the Start menu as well as the user image?

Comment: @gparyani Sort of. It reads it as a Remote Desktop connection, so disables some of the 'Fancy' features of XP, such as the User Image. The Disconnect button allows the VM to just hibernate, and make it quicker to launch

Comment: I tried enabling those features using Group Policy, but it kept crashing when I went to a specific folder.

Comment: I am going to guess (but I could be wrong) that it's hard coded somehow into XP, or it's a special version of Windows XP that Microsoft released *JUST FOR* XP Mode

Comment: If I disable integrated mode like you said, I see a Shut Down button in Start but still no user image...

Comment: Like I said, it was just a guess on that part. If you need the image, and this doesn't answer that part, I'd suggest asking a new question, possibly linking to this one as related. I don't know why the user image doesn't show up for you though

Answer (score 3):

According to [KB927063](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927063):

> This problem occurs if the installation source is specified by using
>   the TSClient share through Universal Naming Convention (UNC) notation.
>   For example, you receive the error when you use the following command:

```
 msiexec /i \\TSClient\Drive\package_name.msi
```

The resolution as provided is to either map a drive to the location where the MSI is located, or to copy it to the local drive of the virtual machine.